# How to do React Native app once the user logs in, then it should be automatically logged in?

Tags: react-native, authentication, get, request, strapi

## login request from API

How to do React Native app once the user logs in, then it should be automatically logged in?
Once logged into the application, it should automatically be able to log in every time.

```
export default class LoginForm extends Component {
  state = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    login: false,
  };
  uri = Info.BaseUri + Info.LoginEndPoint;
  # login request from API #
  login = () => {
    fetch(this.uri, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        identifier: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.user.email == this.state.email) {
          saveUser(data.jwt, data.user);
          this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        alert("Email adresi veya parola hatalı!");
      });
  };
```

Comment: Use [Async Storage](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage) to store the token then on every app start you can restore the token (if it exists) and keep the user logged in

Comment: In case you use `react-navigation` for handling navigation, they have a specific section for [authentication flow](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow).